# How to create a year-month series to use as an index in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to start with the month `2019-01` and then add any number of consequtive months and use that as an index in a pandas dataframe. I've found suggestions that point to using `pd.to_timedelta`, but I keep bumbing into problems.

Here are the details:

If you start with a date and add 5 periods like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date = pd.to_datetime("1st of Jan, 2019")
dates = date+pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5), 'M')
```

Then you get:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-31 10:29:06',
               '2019-03-02 20:58:12', '2019-04-02 07:27:18',
               '2019-05-02 17:56:24'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

You can easily remove the day and time parts, and remove duplicates to handle the double `2019-01` like this:

```
dates = dates.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
dates = dates.drop_duplicates()
```

But as you can see, `2019-02` is missing:

```
Index(['2019-01', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05'], dtype='object')
```

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **`pandas.date_range`** :

```
pd.date_range(date, periods=5, freq='M').strftime('%Y-%m')
```

[out]

```
Index(['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create `PeriodIndex` by [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.period_range.html):

```
dates = pd.period_range(date, periods=5, freq='M')
print (dates)
PeriodIndex(['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05'], 
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

Your solution should be working if add 2 days:

```
dates = (date + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5), unit='M') + pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')).strftime('%Y-%m')

print (dates)
Index(['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05'], dtype='object')
```

Verify:

```
dates = (date + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(120), unit='M') + pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d'))
        .month.value_counts()

print (dates)

12    10
11    10
10    10
9     10
8     10
7     10
6     10
5     10
4     10
3     10
2     10
1     10
dtype: int64
```